# como diminuo um arquivo csv de 3 gb, para conseguir importar no pandas no google colab?

Tags: python, arquivo, csv, ciência-de-dados

No colab da um erro:

> "A sessão falhou depois de usar toda a RAM disponível. Se você tiver
> interesse em acessar ambientes de execução com mais memória RAM,
> confira o Colab Pro."

Eu queria diminuir o arquivo csv para nao dar mais este problema ao importar, o que faço?
Ele é muito grande 3 GB, devido a isto a RAM disponível no google Colab não é suficiente para importá-lo.
O arquivo esta em https://download.inep.gov.br/microdados/microdados_enem_2019.zip , e so fazer o download se precisar. Este e o caminho ao baixar no drive para pegar o arquivo que estou me referindo **/content/drive/MyDrive/Microdados_Enem_2019/DADOS/MICRODADOS_ENEM_2019.csv**.
Se poderem me ajudar a diminuir o arquivo csv para conseguir importa-lo no google colab, agradeceria muito, e simples e so me ajudar a diminuir a quantidade de linha no arquivo csv, neste arquivo possui 5 milhao, seria mais facil se tivesse meio milhao ou menos, para conseguir importar no colab.

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')

import pandas as pd

#aqui que dá o erro, ao importar o arquivo csv, eu só queria diminuir ele para conseguir importar
microdados = pd.read_csv('/content/drive/MyDrive/Microdados_Enem_2019/DADOS/MICRODADOS_ENEM_2019.csv',sep=";", encoding="ISO-8859-1")
microdados.head()
```

Comment: A mensagem termina com `confira o Colab Pro`... Significa que você tem que pagar por um serviço para ter mais memória disponível. Minha sugestão caso você não tenha orçamento para isso é instala o Jupyter na sua máquina. Acredito que dividir o arquivo não seja a solução, pois vc terá que carregar todos do mesmo jeito, certo?

Comment: Você tentou abrir o arquivo com um editor de texto, excluir algumas linhas e salvar? Não entendi o que sua dúvida tem a ver com programação.

Comment: Se você procurar a [documentação](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) do Pandas também vai ver que a função `read_csv` pode receber um parâmentro `nrows` que especifica quantas linhas do arquivo você quer ler.

Comment: isso mesmo que eu queria @fernandosavio , muito obrigado! nao sabia deste parametro do read_csv "nrows", obrigado mesmo!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sugiro que você faça o download de um aplicativo que tem o objetivo de dividir um arquivo CSV gigante em pequenos *pedaços*, ou seja, em vários arquivos CSVs menores que apresentarão uma quantidade de linhas definidas por você.

Sugiro o aplicativo  [Split CSV File](https://sourceforge.net/projects/splitcsv/). Com este aplicativo, você informa quantas linhas quer em cada arquivo menor. No seu caso, basta parametrizar o campo **"Line Count"** com a quantidade de linhas e clicar no botão **"Split File"**.

[image: Aplicativo simples Split CSV File]

É um aplicativo simples, basta executar, não precisa instalar, já utilizei várias vezes.
Caso queira ver outras opções de aplicativos, consulte este site [sobre como dividir arquivo CSV](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-split-a-huge-csv-excel-workbook-into-seperate-files/)

**Caso particular**

Para resolver seu caso em particular, baixei seu arquivo e o dividi em arquivos com 100 mil linhas. Como você disse que gostaria de trabalhar com 500 mil linhas ou menos, estou disponibilizando um arquivo zip com 5 CSVs de 100 mil linhas, basta clicar [nesse link MICRODADOS_ENEM_2019_500_mil_Linhas.zip](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1es3Z5W3D7oyqmquGHhsJ6h3QHW0sDdZS/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Nossa, Muito Obrigado!